# Javascript Remove object from array not removing the selected

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular 5 and I have created a function to remove an object from an array:

Here is the data:

```
this.widgets = [
   { id: 1, title: 'Object 1', config: { row: 1, col: 1, sizex: 1 }}
   { id: 2, title: 'Object 2', config: { row: 1, col: 2, sizex: 1 }}
];
```

And here is the function:

```
removeObj(id) {
  this.widgets.splice( this.widgets.indexOf(id), 1 );
}
```

This in the html part of the component I have:

```
<div *ngFor="let widget of widgets" [(ngWidget)]="widget.config">
    <button (click)="removeObj(widget.id)">X</button>
    <div class="title">{{widget.title}}</div>
    <p>{{widget.id}}</p>
</div>
```

What I need it to do it to only remove the selected object but it's just removing the first object instead.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with *array.prototype.filter*:

```
this.widgets = [
    { id: 1, title: 'Object 1', config: { row: 1, col: 1, sizex: 1 }}
    { id: 2, title: 'Object 2', config: { row: 1, col: 2, sizex: 1 }}
];

removeObj(id) {
    this.widgets = this.widgets.filter(widget => widget.id !== id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `removeObj` function you have to search for the id passed in the parameter. You cannot just use `indexOf` to get the index.

```
removeObj(id) {
   var index = -1;
   this.widgets.forEach((widget, i) => {
        if(widget.id === id) {
            index= i;
            return;
        }
   });
   this.widgets.splice( this.widgets.indexOf(index), 1 );
}
```

Comment: you can go with `findIndex` instead of using `loop`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  removeObj(id) {
  let index = this.widgets.findIndex(function (o) {
            return o.id === id;
        })
  this.widgets.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the following one line of code

```
delete this.widgets[this.widget.indexOf(id)];
```

Comment: `this.widget.indexOf(id)` what is the result of this line?

Comment: It return the 0-based index of the given id corresponding to his position in the array

Comment: Please take a look at this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score 0):

ID is your object property and not array index. You can do this:

```
<div *ngFor="let widget of widgets; let i = index" [(ngWidget)]="widget.config">
    <button (click)="removeObj(i)">X</button>
    <div class="title">{{widget.title}}</div>
    <p>{{widget.id}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to map the array before splicing :

```
removeObj(id) {
   widgets.splice((widgets.map(o => o.id)).indexOf(id) , 1);
}
```